# How to solve chrome driver's not working error in Linux

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

THIS IS MY FIRST QUESTION IN LIFETIME. PLEASE HELP ME!
I used selenium, chrome, chromedriver to crawl some finance data.
it worked well in original server. So, I just use it in new server.
But, it doesn't work at all and I don't know why this happens.... :(
whenever I try to execute code `driver.get(url)`, it just gives me endless waiting and after 10 minute, it results in this error message.
The only difference between original server and new server is chrome and chromedriver's version.

original server : chrome(92.0.4515.159), chromedriver(92.0.4515.107)

new server : chrome(95.0.4638.69), chromedriver(95.0.4638.69 (6a1600ed572fedecd573b6c2b90a22fe6392a410-refs/branch-heads/4638@{#984})

[error_message - please look at it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymtk8.png)

#---------------------------------This is full code ---------------------
#---- all the codes worked well but last one doesn't work----------------

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible =0, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()
url = 'https://card-search.naver.com/list'
path = '/data/WebCrawl/IPO/chromedriver'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options = options)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Do you have any of Xvfb, Xephyr or Xvnc installed ?

Comment: Thanks for comment sir, I already installed Xvfb

Comment: I also found one more differences between original server and new server.
when I execute google-chrome in new server, it gives errors that ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144) open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq : No such file or directory (2)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)